# Binary Search With Char Array

Tags: c++, binary-search

I am trying to implement a binary search to search through a char array. When executed, the program repeatedly says "The letter B was found at the element with index 1" and never changes, despite changing the input. I am unsure of where I am going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool binarySearch(char usedLetters[], int used, char letterToFind);

int main()
{
char a[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

int userValue;

cout << "Enter a letter: " << endl;
cin >> userValue;

int result = binarySearch(a, 8, userValue);

if(result == true)
{
    cout << "The letter " << a[result] << " was found at the"
            " element with index " << result << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "The letter " << userValue << " was not found. " << endl;
}
}

bool binarySearch(char usedLetters[], int used, char letterToFind)
{
int first = 0;
int last = used - 1;
int mid;
int position = -1;
bool found = false;

while (!found && first <= last)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (usedLetters[mid] == letterToFind)
        {
            found = true;
            position = mid;
        }
    else if (usedLetters[mid] > letterToFind)
        last = mid - 1;
    else
        first = mid + 1;
}
return position;
}
```

Comment: You're using 8 as the size of the array to binary search, even though the array `a` has size 3. That might be a problem.

Comment: You are accessing array out-of-bounds.. You should pass the size of the array to your search function and figure out the mid based on the size.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know the array a does not change, but shouldn't I be getting a different result each time I run the program? For example, on the first run I search for 'A', and on the second run I search for 'B'?

Comment: @user6470814 I was looking at the code wrong.  Look at templatetypedef's comment.  You have UB/wrong mid point..

Comment: I fixed the 8 to the correct size, but I am still getting the same error. Is this still an array out-of-bounds issue?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what did you change the value to?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just hard-coded 3 for now.

Comment: Shouldn't userValue be a char instead of an int?

Comment: @GerardoGálvez Yes, it should. I have changed it to a char. That still didn't solve the problem though...

Comment: `binarySearch` return type should be `int`, not a `bool`. Then the check `(result == true)` needs to change too (maybe use `-1` for false result).

Comment: Having it return bool will always make the return 1 if the character is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binary search returns a `bool`, and what you are returning is the position in which the letter was found, or -1 otherwise. Your function will return 1 (true) every time the position found is different that 0, that's why it always outputs that it found B at index 1.

Just change your binary search to return an `int` and change your conditions to:

```
if (result == -1)
    // Not found
else
    // Found
```